# How to solve "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable" problem in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvpTO.png)

Problem is occurring with variable called "libraryForm"

Answer (score 0):

To fix it don't declare the same variable in the same block.

You can't have the same variable name in the same block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are assigning **libraryForm** multiple times (most likely at the global scope)

Based on the limited nature of your screen shot, it seems like the solution to your problem would be to only assign **libraryForm** variable once to the proper HTML element in your code

Your solution would consist of :

- getting rid of the unused assignment of **libraryForm** on line 18
- Leaving the single
  assignment of **libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryform')** on line 22
- getting rid of the duplicate assignment later down in your
  code.

It seems like you should learn more about the **difference of let vs var**, **block scope**, and **variable hoisting**.

https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_let.asp